# Date modified time is showing UTC timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I am having some difficulties understanding what is going on with this issue i am having. i have created a web server using centOS, i have an html form that i have created on the server. the problem is that when i enter information in the form, when i look at the modified time, it is showing a UTC time rather than an EST time. the reason that this is an issue is because the way i have the file being saved as is using the date. so if the time is saying that it is 12:01am but the information was inputted at 8:01pm, instead of overwriting the file, is going to create a new file with tomorrow's date on it. i have set the timezone to EST in my php code, but it does not seem to accept my timezone.

this is the php code that i have.

```
if(isset($_POST['mydrivers']))  
{  
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $month = date('M');
    $fp = file('Reports/Shortage/' .$month. '/Shortage'.date('m-d-y'). ".csv");
    //$fi = fopen('driver'.date('m-d-y'). ".csv", "a");
    $header=array("Date", "Driver", "Customer #", "Invoice #", "Product Description", "Size", "CS", "Btls", "CHK Itls");
    $driver = $_POST['drivers'];
    $dates = $_POST['dates'];
    $custnum = $_POST['customernum'];
    $invnum = $_POST['invoicenum'];
    $proddesc = $_POST['proddes'];
    $sz = $_POST['size'];
    $case = $_POST['cs'];
    $bottle = $_POST['btls'];
    $chkit = $_POST['chkitls'];
    $result = '';
    $search = "Driver";
    $line_number = false;


    while(list($key, $line) = each($fp) and !$line_number)
    {
        $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE);
    }

    if($line_number)
    {
        $result .= 
                        $dates. " ,". $driver. " ,". $custnum. ", ". $invnum. ", ". $proddesc. ", ". $sz. " ,". $case. ", ". $bottle. ", ". $chkit. "\r\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= implode(",",$header). "\r\n".
                        $dates. " ,". $driver. ", ". $custnum. " ,". $invnum. ", ". $proddesc. ", ". $sz. ", ". $case. " ,". $bottle. ", ". $chkit. "\r\n";
    }

    /*foreach ($fp as $file)
    {
        if(substr($file,0,8) != 'header 1')
        {
            $result .= implode(",",$header). "\r\n".
                        $driver. " ". $dates. " ". $custnum. " ". $invnum. " ". $proddesc. " ". $sz. " ". $case. " ". $bottle. " ". $chkit. "\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $result .= 
                    $driver. " ". $dates. " ". $custnum. " ". $invnum. " ". $proddesc. " ". $sz. " ". $case. " ". $bottle. " ". $chkit. "\r\n";
        }

    }*/

    if(!is_dir('Reports/Shortage/'.$month))
    {
        mkdir('Reports/Shortage/'.$month, 0777, true);
    }
    file_put_contents('Reports/Shortage/'.$month. '/Shortage'.date('m-d-y').".csv", $result, FILE_APPEND);
    //myfputcsv($fp, $result);
    echo "data added!!!";
```

is this the correct way to set the timezone, or am i doing this completely wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try "America/New_York":

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

See the list of timezones here:  http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: I just tried that, and i still get the same results. the time is still showing as UTC.

Comment: "The time" being what, exactly?  There's no code here that's not a date of "m-d-y", which, for most of the day would be the same whether you're in NYC or London ...  are we referring to server time at the command prompt?  Calls to the Database?  Perhaps you want to set the timezone in php.ini?

Comment: the time that i am referring to is the modify time. when i go to the IP of the server of where the program is, i look in the directory and look at the date modify, it shows the current date, but the time will be 5 hours ahead. for example, i add in a new item, run my script and it overwrites the file if it is there and appends the new information. when i look back in the directory, it will displayed changed 8/11/2016 10:18:13 pm. The time that it shows when the file was changed is the time i am referring to. i don't know if it is a server setting i need to change or what.

Comment: just wanted to let you know that i found the solution.

Comment: And that it was to set the server to the correct TZ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But the crazy thing is that even when I set the TZ on the server to America/New_York, that did not work still. i had to run the code that i posted in my answer. `date MMDDhhmmYYYY` and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to the problem. Even though I was setting the timezone in my file, I actually had to reconfigure the time on the server itself. I logged into the server and ran this simple line of code:

`date MMDDhhmmYYYY`

I remember that I had already set the timezone settings on the server, so I am not sure why they did not stick, but this has solved my issue.